# ViewModel is always null when using .ajax to post to MVC 4 controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

**My jQuery/HTML:**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {

    <input name="ImageName" id="ImageName" type="hidden" />
    <input name="XPos" id="XPos" type="hidden" />
    <input name="YPos" id="YPos" type="hidden" />
    <input name="Height" id="Height" type="hidden" />
    <input name="Width" id="Width" type="hidden" /> 

    <button id="submit" value="submit">Create it!</button>
}


$('form').submit(function () {

    var parameters = [];
    parameters.push({
        ImageName: $('#imagename').val(),
        XPos: $('#xpos').val(),
        YPos: $('#ypos').val(),
        Height: $('#height').val(),
        Width: $('#width').val()
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(parameters));

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Home")',
        type: 'Post',
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            //yadda
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          //yadda
        }
    });
```

**This is my ViewModel:**

```
public class Image{

    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public double Xpos { get; set; }
    public double Ypos { get; set; }
    public double Height{ get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
}
```

**And here is my Controller.**

This is what the JSON.stringify(parameters) looks like:

```
[{"ImageName":"https://domain.com/test.jpg","XPos":"347.98614501953125","YPos":"435.45140838623047","Height":"20","Width":"80.39999999999999"}] 


    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(Image i) {
         //p always has null values
    }
```

Why does my ViewModel always contain null values?

Comment: jquery is case sensitive,  your fields all have id's with capitalization but the jquery selectors are all lower case

Comment: Why aren't you using the razor helpers for your input fields?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to send the data.

Comment: Regarding case sensitivity, notice that the parameters contains the value, this was a typo when entering the question.

Comment: The Razor helpers didn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Also you are sending in a `IEnumerable/Array[]<Image>` per your JSON.

Comment: When I used .serialize(), I get this error: Invalid JSON primitive: ImageName.

Comment: to serialize a form it should be `$('#formid').serialize()` or in your attached event `$(this).serialize()`.

Comment: You can try `Create([FromBody]Image i)` to try to force Web Api's hand a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your error is that you are using array. Try like this.

```
var parameters = {
    ImageName: $('#imagename').val(),
    XPos: $('#xpos').val(),
    YPos: $('#ypos').val(),
    Height: $('#height').val(),
    Width: $('#width').val()
};
```

Or change the input parameter to

```
public JsonResult Create(IEnumerable<Image> i)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an Javascript Array of an Object.  This does not match the signature of you method.

```
[
  {
    "ImageName":"https://domain.com/test.jpg",
    "XPos":"347.98614501953125",
    "YPos":"435.45140838623047",
    "Height":"20",
    "Width":"80.39999999999999"
  }
]
```

I would start using some of the built in features of the frameworks you are using to do the heavy lifting.

In your views:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImageName);
```

In Jquery:

```
$('form').submit(function () {

    var serializedForm = $(this).serialize();

    console.log(serializedForm );

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Home")',
        type: 'Post',
        data: serializedForm ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            //yadda
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          //yadda
        }
    });
```

Comment: When i do this I get this error: Invalid JSON primitive: ImageName.

Comment: I did figure out the error was I was sending a collection/Array, not just an object which was the issue.